# An error show "The method XXX is undefined for the type XXX"... Is there something wrong with my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

Long story short, I want to create using my own `JFrame`, since I'm using `SpringLayout`, it's much easier for me not to use `extends JFrame`.

Instead I got an error when I'm try to call the frame in 
`public static void main(String[] args)`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DatingMatch
{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dating Match");
  Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
  SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();

  private JMenuBar mainbar = new JMenuBar();
  private JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("FILE");
  private JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("HELP");
  private JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("CLOSE");
  private JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("ABOUT");
  private JMenuItem help = new JMenuItem("HELP");

  private JLabel name = new JLabel("NAME :");
  private JTextField nameF = new JTextField(40);

  private JLabel address = new JLabel ("CITY :");
  private JTextField addressF = new JTextField(40);

  private JLabel phoneNum = new JLabel("PHONE NO. : ");
  private JTextField phoneNumF = new JTextField(40);

  private JLabel gender = new JLabel("GENDER");
  private String genderS[] = {"MALE","FEMALE"};
  private JComboBox genderC = new JComboBox(genderS);

  private JButton next = new JButton("NEXT");


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DatingMatch frame = new DatingMatch();
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Comment: DatingMatch is not a JFrame so you can't invoke a method from the JFrame class. As the last statement of your DatingMatch constructor you can invoke the setVisible(...) method on the frame variable.

Comment: Your class is not deriving from JPanel so it does not have the functions of JPanel. If you want a setVisible function, then you have to write it in your class. (That function can call the setVisible function on the JFrame instance that you stored in your class.

Comment: The "kludge fix" in the `main` is `frame.frame.setVisible(true);`. Her, the first `frame` is the instance of `DatingMatch`. The 2nd `frame` is the `JFrame` member variable.